# Android Kotlin New intent on click event from recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I've just started learning android development with Kotlin.

I have a recycler view that lists items.

I'm trying to create onClick event for the item and then start a new intent and pass along the item id.

I'm getting an error when trying to instantiate the Intent "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied". I think it's because I cannot access the context of the view?

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.id = events[position][0]
    holder.title.text = events[position][1]

    if (events[position][2] == events[position][3]) {
        holder.date.text = events[position][2]
    } else {
        holder.date.text = events[position][2] + " - " + events[position][3]
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        v: View -> Unit


        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick for ID: " + holder.id)

        val intent = Intent(this, EventDetail::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("id", holder.id)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: maybe try val intent = Intent(this@YourActivity,EventDetail::class.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a `context` for intent so you can get it form the `activity` or `fragment` that are associated with this `adapter` and pass it to your intent or you can get it from any view in your inflated layout like this

```
val context=holder.title.context
val intent = Intent( context, EventDetail::class.java)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

or you can make a listener that your `activity` or `fragment` implement it and you can on it's callback create your intent like this

`val intent= Intent( this@YourCalssname,EventDetail::class.java)`

Comment: I tried `holder.title.context` but then I get an error on `startActivity(intent)`. Type mismatch. Requied: Context, Found: Intent

Comment: I still get the same error. I've added a screenshot of the error

Comment: you forget context `context.startActivity(intent)`

Answer (score 6):

**This Comes Under OnBindviewholder in Kotlin**
'

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v ->
            val intent = Intent(v.context, QuestionsActi::class.java)
            v.context.startActivity(intent)

}
```

'

Answer (score 1):

you can use holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)[here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Patze.png)

I solved it like this

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXuMl.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am voting to close it, as the code is in form of image, secondly, this is the exact code as the other codes posted previously.